# how to configure MessageChannelPartitionHandler to poll partition result using job repo

Tags: spring-batch

Does anyone know how to configure MessageChannelPartitionHandler to poll partition results from db instead of aggregating jms response from each slave?

I am trying to use this as current aggregator is giving out of memory error after a while job is running. Looks like master node is not releasing memory.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the code of MessageChannelPartitionHandler, all we need is DataSource and JobExplorer reference. You can also configure polling interval but if you dont provide , default is 10sec.